# Store and download a file from database using laravel

Tags: laravel, download, path, storage, store

I would like on button press to download a file from database and at the same time to store it on server. There is the used code for download.

```
$objects = Obj::get()->toArray();
   $time = Carbon::now();
    $name = "Inventory_Snapshot_".$time;
    $export_file = \Excel::create($name, function($excel) use ($objects) {
        $excel->sheet("Objects", function($sheet) use ($objects)
        {
            $sheet->fromArray($objects);
        });
    });
    $export_file->download();
```

I need somehow to save this file to server too, if the name doesn't exist yet. The path for the stored file has to be  public/resources/snap
Thank you!

Comment: What does `\Excel::create` do? Does it create a file on disk or in memory?

Comment: it creates a file in memory which will be downloaded from browser.

Comment: What library are you using? Usually you'd just do `\File::put(public_path('resources/snap/filename.xlsx', $data)` but I have no idea how you'd get the raw data because that depends on the library you're using

Comment: I found the solution: $objects = Obj::get()->toArray();
  
        $time = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
      
        $name = "VAG_Inventory_Snapshot_".$time;
        $export_file = \Excel::create($name, function($excel) use ($objects) {
            $excel->sheet("Objects", function($sheet) use ($objects)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($objects);
            });
        })->store('xls',storage_path('..\public\resources\Exported_Snapshots'));

Comment: i had to add ->store(....) at the end of $export_file = ...